# Error: Failed to lookup view "skills.ejs" in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm only 1 month in to my full stack program and am trying to render index and details pages on a local server. Please be gentle. :)

I've tried all I can think of and have spent days looking at this and banging my head off the keyboard. I can't seem to figure out why the skills.ejs file won't render in localhost:3000/skills or why I can't navigate to the details page for my array key:item pairs. I thought I had all routing done correctly, and the proper references to the state and controllers.

With the screenshot supplied, any thoughts you may have would be most appreciated. I can get the index to render, but not the skills.ejs file.

[VS Code pane and server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXnwO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for `skills.ejs` within the `views` directory. The issue seems to be that `skills.ejs` is actually in `views/skills/skills.ejs`. Try changing line 12 in `skills-ctrl.js` to `res.render('skills/skills.ejs');`